# npm don't install module every time

Tags: node.js, npm, deb

The problem is that `npm install` rebuilds and reinstalls a module every time, even if the module is already installed.

I've made a .deb package that among other things installs a nodejs app.

But that app needs *express* and *sqlite3* modules. I install them in the postinst of .deb:

```
npm install -g express sqlite3
```

And never remove it.

So, during .deb installation *sqlite3* js module is recompiled and reinstalled every time. That takes forever on Raspberry.

How to make it work correctly?

Comment: I don't know that it would be right, but you can use update instead of install. In this case npm would check for outdated module and install newer version if exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm going with:

```
nodejs_modules="express sqlite3"
nodejs_modules_installed="$(npm list -g --depth=0)"

for m in $nodejs_modules; do
    if ! echo "$nodejs_modules_installed" | grep -q "\\s$m"@; then
        npm install -g "$m"
    else
        npm update -g "$m"
    fi
done
```